# Zend Framework 2: Fatal error: Class 'Application\Model\Area_mst' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I got this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Application\Model\Area_mst' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebudx\module\Application\Module.php on line 87

Is it okay to have underscores on your Tablenames?

Comment: Can you post the complete Module.php class **and** your Area_mst model?

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to have underscores in your table names, however the file would be AreaMst.php. It will replace all "_" items into CamelCase.